# How can I create a surface of evenly space hemispheres?

Tags: modifiers, particles, geometry, dupli-groups

I'm new to blender, and I'm having issues trying to create hemispheres. I have been attempting to use nurb spheres and trying to split them in half using a selected vertex and this hasn't been working. I would also like to be able to add fibers that are perpendicular to the hemisphere's surface. Ideally, I would be able to make one of these fibrous hemispheres and then just copy the shape to evenly space them. I would much appreciate any tips on how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I didn't get what kind of surface you would like to get cover with hemispheres: could you show what you have achieved so far and a quick sketch of the wanted result?

Comment: I am not able to show any progress because I didn't save any of my progress(I wasn't really getting anywhere). Here's an image link of what I'm attempting to do(please excuse my artistic abilities): https://imgur.com/urev8RH

Comment: Ok! You can probably achieve similar results with duplifaces, or a particle system, or the "Tissue add-on", or an array modifier: each one has its pro's and con's.. tell us more about the surface: is it only a plain, square, plane or you plan to make it much complex?

Comment: A square plane would suffice for my purposes. The major component of the design is the hemispheres with the fibers. The fibers must be perpendicular to the surface in the local region. Are those things you mentioned other programs, or are they extensions of Blender? If the former, are they easier to use?

Comment: They are in Blender (actually you find all of them in the official build, apart from the tissue add-on you can download [here](https://github.com/alessandro-zomparelli/tissue)). None of them is hard to understand or use, they are all just differents way of duplicating the same object. May I ask if need to use Nurbs instead of Meshes and how you imagine the fibers?

Comment: I just wasn't really clear on the difference between the two...The fibers should be cylindrical and evenly distributed over the hemispherical surface. As far as how many there are per unit area, I'm not really concerned with that right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Grid of hemispheres

As long as you don't need to populate curved surfaces, the simplest, quickest and more flexible way to create a grid made by the same object is probably using two stacked **Array** modifiers.

Start from creating one hemisphere.

[image]

As we'll make the fibers by duplicating a fiber upon each face, we'll need to start with a **Ico Sphere**, which is made by evenly sized faces.

Add one and increase the number of Subdivison in the operator panel you find on the left.

[image]

Then delete the bottom vertices and add an Array modifier to replicate the geometry along the X axis. Increase the relative offset to adjust the distance between the hemispheres.

[image]

After that we'll have to add a second modifier to duplicate the object along the Z axis

[image]

The grid has been created. The first parameter of each modifier controls the duplication count.

### Fibers

Go to the particle system tab and crate a new Hair System for the object. Enable Advanced, set 1 particle per face and enable Use modifier Stack option in order to take into account all the modifiers previuvsly created.

[image]

Create a "Fiber" sample object to be replicated where the hairs are. To do so, model it the way you want it, just make sure it is pointing toward the Y axis and his rotation is 0,0,0 as in the picture below:

[image]

Go to the hair system's render panel, choose Object and point the field to the Fiber sample object:

[image]

[image]